# Where to put custom data

Tags: android

In a typical Android project you have the `res/drawable` directories where you can put images but I have some special custom binary files.

Where do I usually put them and can I access them via the `R-class` then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either in res/raw or res/assets. Read more in the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.htmlBlockquoteAssetManager.).

About files in res/raw:

> Arbitrary files to save in their raw
>   form. Files in here are not compressed
>   by the system. To open these resources
>   with a raw InputStream, call
>   Resources.openRawResource() with the
>   resource ID, which is R.raw.filename.
>
> However, if you need access to
>   original file names and file
>   hierarchy, you might consider saving
>   some resources in the assets/
>   directory (instead of res/raw/). Files
>   in assets/ are not given a resource
>   ID, so you can read them only using
>   AssetManager.AssetManager.

Comment: thanks, but this raw directory is not generated in a default eclipse project, right?

Comment: Nope; just create it in the /res/ folder and it'll be handled correctly by the build tools.

Answer (score 0):

For such type of resources use res/raw directory.